# Uploading image to Firebase, got an error saying expected blob or file

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

### **Problem**

I am trying to create a social media app where the user can upload images. I am using firebase and firebase storage for the app. I tried uploading an image to firebase, and I got an error:

```
Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in 'put' at index 0: 
Expected Blob or File
```

The image data I am trying to upload must not be a blob, so my question is, how can I fix this code, or how can I upload an image another way?

### **The code**

```
//uri is the path on the phone to the image
uploadImage(uri) {

 var ref = firebase.storage().ref().child('image.jpg');

  let uriParts = uri.split('.');
  let fileType = uri[uri.length - 1];

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('photo', {
    uri,
    name: `photo.${fileType}`,
    type: `image/${fileType}`,
  });

ref.put(formData).then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
});

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

To upload a new file, you should directly update using `ref.put(file)` with file being a File, Blob, or Uint8Array.

[See the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files).

You probably want to grab the Blob using [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs), then upload it:

```
uploadImage(uri) {
    RNFS.readFile(uri).then(file => {
        // Get Storage ref
        const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child('image.jpg');

        const uriParts = uri.split('.');
        const fileType = uri[uri.length - 1];

        const metadata = {
            customMetadata: {
                name: `photo.${fileType}`,
                type: `image/${fileType}`
            }
        };

        ref.put(file, metadata).then(snapshot => {
            console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
        });
    });
};
```